# Maximizing the ratio of multilinear polynomials

Tags: polynomials, nonlinear-optimization, implicit-function-theorem

Consider two [multilinear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilinear_polynomial) Polynomials $A(x_1,x_2,x_3,\dotsc,x_n)$ and $B(x_1,x_2,x_3,\dotsc,x_n)$ of $n > 2$ variables $x_i \in \mathbb{R}$ and their ratio
\begin{equation*}
 F(x_1,x_2,x_3,\dotsc,x_n) = \frac{A(x_1,x_2,x_3,\dotsc,x_n)}{B(x_1,x_2,x_3,\dotsc,x_n)}
\end{equation*}

Define $G$ to be the function obtained from $F$ by substituting $(x_1,x_2)=(t,-t)$ and maximizing over $t$:
\begin{equation*}
G(x_3,\dotsc,x_n) := \max_t F(t,-t,x_3,\dotsc,x_n)
\end{equation*}

Here the maximum is assumed to exist in a local sense, i.e. assume there is a function
$t = f(x_3,\dotsc,x_n)$ that locally parametrizes the solution set of
\begin{equation} 
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} F(t,-t,x_3,\dotsc, x_n)=0.
\end{equation}
such that we have
\begin{equation} 
G(x_3,\dotsc,x_n) :=  F(f(x_3,\dotsc,x_n),-f(x_3,\dotsc,x_n),x_3,\dotsc, x_n)
\end{equation}

**Question**: Can $G$ be written as
\begin{equation*}
G(x_3,\dotsc,x_n) = \frac{\widetilde{A}(x_3,\dotsc,x_n)}{\widetilde{B}(x_3,\dotsc,x_n)}
\end{equation*}
with multilinear polynomials $\widetilde{A},\widetilde{B}$ of the remaining $n-2$ variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in general. E.g., let $n=3$, $A(x_1,x_2,x_3):=1-x_1 x_2+2 x_3 x_2+x_1 x_3$, and  $B(x_1,x_2,x_3):=2-x_1 x_2+x_3 x_2+2 x_1 x_3$. Then for $x_3\in(0,2\sqrt2)$
$$G(x_3)=\max_{t\in\mathbb R}\frac{A(t,-t,x_3)}{B(t,-t,x_3)}
=\frac{x_3^2+2 \sqrt{6 x_3^2+1}+6}{8-x_3^2},$$
which is not the ratio of multilinear polynomials in $x_3$.